# Find unique length of one column by matching other columns

Tags: r, rstudio

So i have this data frame in CSV format: [image: example]

and i would like to know how to find `unique length` of different `lecturer.id` matched by `program.id` and `program.id.ime.`

So my outcome should be variable which would give me **length** of **unique** **lecturer.id** who are teaching English (in my case i can see from the data or picture that this is 10 lecturers), and length of unique lecturer.id who are teaching History and so on. So i would like to generate code that:

**If this lecturer.id matches this program.id than paste length of this program.id.ime which is =10 othervise paste different length**

I am thinking in this direction (but it is not what i want)

```
length(unique(subset(df, lecturer.id==program.id)))
```

I was thinking of using `aggregate`, but I need this in a variable that will produce different lengths according to `program.id` and `program.id.ime`.

So small part of my data frame looks like this

```
lecturer.id<- c(111, 111,112,126,127,132,139,143,155)
program.id<- c(35,35,35,35,44,44,44,42,42)
program.id.ime<- c('English', 'English', 'English', 'English', 
 'History', 'History', 'History', 'Sociology', 'Sociology')

df <- data.frame(lecturer.id, program.id, program.id.ime)
```

So i know that lecturer with id 111 is teaching on program with id 35 and this program name is English. My outcome should be the length or the **number** of all lecturers that are teaching English, and length of all lecturers that are teaching History and so on.

So as I am combining R code with latex (hmisc) my output is a table (because of the data confidentiality I deleted some variables:
[image]

**I would like to generate number in parentheses which is the example of the OUTPUT I want. It is important to generate it automatically by matching columns.**

**The whole point is that I am doing PDF reports for seperate lecturer and I am matching lecturer with his lecture.id based on** `foor-loop`. So output is PDF report for one lecturer and in the table in second picture **I need number of all lecturers on specific course.**

Comment: The numbers you posted in the expected output figure is not matching with the data link you provided.   I guess it must be because you deleted some data?. In my solution, I am getting the lengths of the unique lecturer.id for each group of `program.id.ime` and `program.id`

Comment: yes I deleted some data, but i am working with the csv. file available on a link.

Comment: What are those numbers 62, 29, 28, 14, 48, 56, 14  36?  I am not getting that number from the csv data

Comment: The number of all unique lecturers on a specific course ie. program.id is  `setDT(df1)[, uniqueN(lecturer.id) , program.id]` and that result is not matching with your result.  If I do `setDT(df1)[, .N , program.id]` i.e. including all unique and non-unique, it is still not matching to your expected output

`

Comment: 62, 29, 28, 14 are numbers of some variables which i had to delete), I need that the number of all lecturers of English programs will be like this English (10 lecturers)<-the number in parentheses is the OUTPUT

Comment: Sorry, I am not following you.

Comment: What is `English(106)`.  I find only 10 'English' in program.id.time.

Comment: It is Just an example I made by hand.. In my case is 10. But this has to be done automatically. My goal is write code something like this: If this lecturer.id matches this program.id than paste length of this program.id.ime which is =10 otherwise paste different length.

Comment: Try `setDT(df1)[, list(n= uniqueN(lecturer.id)), .(program.id, program.id.ime)][, program.id.ime:=sprintf('%s (%d)', program.id.ime, n)][, n:=NULL]`

Comment: This produces list of result but I need to have just one number, for example my "variable" should output just one number, let say 9, which is number of lecturers in English calss. The variable number should depend on lecturer.id.

Comment: It gives just one number for `English` i.e `9` and it is giving the length of unique number of `lecturer.id` for `English`.  Sorry, I am not following what your really wanted.  Better would be to show the exact expected outpur rather than some image about results in a different format and different dataset.

Comment: I tried using your example of code, but get this error:could not find function "uniqueN", I tried to install library(devtools)
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE) but still error. I saw that you are using devel.

Comment: Yes, it is wrapper for `length(unique(lecturer.id))`.  So, replace that and it will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Using the data in the link (changed the file name to 'Miha.csv')

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
df1 <- read.csv('Miha.csv', sep=';')
```

Or

```
df1 <- fread('Miha.csv') #in this case, the object will be `data.table`
setDT(df1)[, list(n= uniqueN(lecturer.id)), .(program.id, program.id.ime)
   ][, program.id.ime:=sprintf('%s (%d)', program.id.ime, n)][, n:=NULL]
#   program.id   program.id.ime
#1:         35      English (9)
#2:         44      History (4)
#3:         43    Sociology (8)
#4:         34  Politology (21)
#5:         40 Antropology (62)
#6:         41       Music (65)
#7:        116    Music II (10)
```

In the dataset, each 'program.id.ime' have a single 'program.id', so

```
setDT(df1)[, list(program.id.ime=sprintf('%s (%d)',
      program.id.ime[1L], uniqueN(lecturer.id))) , .(program.id)]
#    program.id   program.id.ime
# 1:         35      English (9)
# 2:         44      History (4)
# 3:         43    Sociology (8)
# 4:         34  Politology (21)
# 5:         40 Antropology (62)
# 6:         41       Music (65)
# 7:        116    Music II (10)
```

Comment: @Miha Please update it in your post using the edit option as people may not look in the comments for data

Comment: I edited. So your code gives me list of names, but I need length as numeric. So Output should be one number wich represents the length of different lecturers according to program.id and program.id.ime

Comment: @Miha My code gives `n= 3, 3, 2`  as per your example I don't know whether you are using the same code.

Comment: Can I upload csv file or send it somewhere?

Comment: @Miha Could you upload it in dropbox and post the link?  Also, can you show the expected output as per the example you provided

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/doos7got1m45upp/data.frame.csv?dl=0  I will post a picture of outpute because i have it in a table

Comment: As I am doing PDF reports for one lecturer, output should be the number of all lecturers in matched program.id.ime

Comment: @Miha Can you edit the post to show the `for` loop that got this values.

Comment: Due to the nature of code i would prefer to send it to email or somewhere else.